# Accessing Windows harddrive wrecked with viruses, trojans, etc using Linux

Tags: linux, virus-removal

I am in possession of a windows harddrive that was recently infected and as a new user to Linux, I wish to salvage as much data as possible from the harddrive. A few questions though.

- Can the viruses affect my Linux installation in any way?
- What is the best way to salvage as much information as possible whilst ensuring the files I am attempting to save are not infected and that do not infect my installation of Linux?

Appreciate any other advise and tips.

Comment: [Cleaning windows viruses from linux](http://superuser.com/q/9385)

Comment: @Sathya - Thanks. I had a read of that post however it did not answer my question whether if there is a possibility to infect Linux. I also amended my question slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former, no, Viruses are usually OS specific, thought there have been a few multiplatform ones as of late

Imaging before  recovery is often a good idea, in case something went wrong.

As for salvaging information, run an antivirus or three on it before mounting it on a linux livec for actual salvage to make sure the contents of the drive get cleaned up first- I'd recommend running [multiple livecd AV distros](http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/) --- [MS has one in system sweeper](http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper) , and there's a few more - for example [avira](http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-avira-antivir-rescue-system).Clean out the disc first before you do anything, and what you salvage SHOULD be virus free.